# How to install calabash in windows?

Tags: android, calabash

I was trying to install calabash-cucumber and calabash-android in windows for last 3 days.I have set ruby path variable in environment also. But i'm getting below error..

`C:\>gem install cucumber` 
error likes below,

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cucumber' (>= 0) in any repository
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party di
d not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz)

```
C:\>gem install calabash-android
```

Error likes below,

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'calabash-android' (>= 0) in any repository
```

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: A connection attempt failed because the connected party di
d not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/
latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I'm new to calabash mobile automation testing. Please any one help to resolve this problem. I'm eagerly learn to calabash mobile automation tool. Thanks for advance..

Answer (score 10):

These are the steps that I took and I successfully can run a calabash test on an Android device using Windows 7, 64 bit:

Install Ant (1.9)
    http://ant.apache.org/

Install Ruby
    http://rubyinstaller.org/
    Install the 1.9.3 version (not the 2.0.0 or higher yet).

Install Ruby DevKit
    http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads
    https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Install Calabash
    https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md

Be sure PATHs are set correctly.
Be sure to follow the instructions given on the web-pages mentioned above.

Maybe your internet connection or the remote server were temporarily down, but it all should work.

Comment: It's not easy - I ended up going with it on OSX which was still a nause. I will be setting up my windows box now I have it working though. Getting the resigning was an issue for my android stuff and the errors were useless in finding the source of the issue. Use adb - adb logcat is your friend.

Comment: Followed these steps on Windows 7 64bit (Installed ruby 1.9.3) and it worked great! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't **set the proxy environment variable**, set it from command prompt by typing this command

```
set HTTP_PROXY = http://your-proxy-address:your-port-number
```

Your command prompt maybe unaware of your proxy IP and port, which is the reason for this error.